How do i join separate part on my character without compromising the rigging
So i wanted to export this character toa game engine, i saw the requirement for this is the character preferred to be one mesh. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27woi8FsgAU&t=246s
The problem is my character has separate mesh, there are 8 mesh that are separated. First four is for the eye part, i parented those to a custom bone i made by duplicating some rigify generated bones and moved it to new layer, next 4 parts are the gum and the teeth, i parented those to DEF-teeth, same happens with the lower.
I joined the lower teeth and then assign weight=1 DEF-teeth.001 when i move the jaw the teeth wont follow, it's a bit weird since the DEF bones i assigned weight also moved if i move the controller.
For the eye i haven't yet figure out a way to join the mesh. The eyeball is parented to a custom bones i made, the bones lies in the rotation axis of the eyeball.
Next thing is my character has shapekey that are driven by bones, chatgpt said that can be done using morph target.
I don't know how to join the meshes into a single object, i also attached my file to examine. I want to know the workflow on how do i fuse the meshes into single object that still retain capabilities of the separated part rig since the part is actually parented to a specific bone.
I really don't know what to do
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n0rDFoNlvtjlWzuslymM4MG37alDH1Wt?usp=drive_link

There are so many issues to be fixed in this character in order to be correctly exported that it's impossible to resume all of them into an answer, so I will address you only on one of the main: if you give weight to some vertices targeting a bone/vertex group that originally wasn't meant to be a deforming bone, you have to tick its "Deform" option in order to have it working.
This is true also for bones like "Teeth", because originally they are meant to be used with direct bone parenting (which is not directly exportable on fbx).

You should also clarify which is the engine you want to export to, because they can have different behaviours and requests: in general, Unity and UE can import rigs based on vertex weights, shape keys and drivers, while they do not recognize direct bone parenting, bone constraints, lattices, curves, and there can be struggles on bone hierarchy, non uniform scaling and connected bones behaviours.
On the other hand having the mesh composed of separate objects is not an issue.
I would suggest you to start importing simpler characters, in order to get familiar with what you need to prepare for a correct export.


Thanks for the solution on bones deform issue! To clarify i want to export this into unreal using fbx, also later if export is successful, i want to add animation to my rig in unreal. I've tried exporting and i encountered this issue although i think i shall ask this on unreal stack exchange "skeleton has nonunique bones" the other issue on log panel is just uv unwrap on parented mesh, I have a follow up question: do i need to bake the texture into 1 single texture cause my character consisted of different uv maps. Thank you!

When exporting a rig to Unreal, you loose nearly all mechanism functionalities, that have to be reconstructed directly into the game engine, using its own blueprints (or code). The exported rig will be a simple set of bones with names and hierarchy, without any automated option (like IK/FK), pratically all DEF bones without any bone constraint.

I'm sorry if my message lacks clarity. I'm intending to animate in blender and export the animation just like https://youtu.be/L4OcpF7-YB0?si=MW5OVKRaG6dDJWzU this guys does. I also notice that my spline IK that was made for fur spline tentacle made the fbx failed to be imported in unreal due to naming, deselecting them and not exporting them made the import success. I'm gonna follow some tuts on preparing game assets. Thank you for your help!

[CASE CLOSED] i think the answer i get from Josh is enough to resolve my issue , from there i think i can pick what went wrong. I'm gonna get Pierrick's animation+rigging course later on, which i think will explain all of things that happen under the hood. <Thank you!!!> btw this is my first complete character i made (model -> animation).
